# Trying to loop an API call until condition is met

Tags: python, api, while-loop

**Background** - I am trying to create a function that continues to call an API (response = `api_response`) whilst a condition is true. When the condition is False, the function should instead return `api_response`.

**Function** - this is my function in it's current form. I have completely confused myself, and therefore written some notes, so you can 'try' and understand my thought process:

```
def api_call():
#   Getting required variables by calling other functions
    key, secret, url = ini_reader()
    endpoint_url = endpoint_initializer()
    
#   In these 3x lines of code I'm trying to ensure the API is called.
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url = endpoint_url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(key, secret), headers = {"My-firm": "482"})
        api_response = json.loads(response.text)

#       I am now trying to take the returned 'api_response' and see if a condition is met / trying extract certain key pair values,
#       which tell me the data isn't available. If the condition is met (keys are in the response / data isn't available), I am expecting
#       the API to continue being called again and the loop continues to iterate until the condition is not met, at which point I am expecting to simply have 'api_response' returned.  
    try:
            id_value = "id"
            res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
            id_value = "".join(res1)
            percent_value = "percent_complete"
            res2 = (tuple(api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '') for key, val in api_response.items()))
            print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {res2} complete!')
            time.sleep(5)
#       If the above condition isn't met, then return 'api_response', which includes the data.
        except:
            return api_response
api_call()
```

**Issue** - currently, I can't seem to get my loop to function properly, in that it calls the API once and then dies. Can anyone put me right, with the correct loop to implement?

Comment: Why are you using using `try / except`? The statements in the `try` clause will never fail

Comment: You inspired me to revisit this, and very quickly resolve. Thank you @gimix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a useful user comment, I identified the `try` statement wasn't testing anything and would infinitely loop, Instead, I used `while True` to start and infinite loop, and captured the API response, before using a `try` statement to test a condition (`if "meta not in api_response`). If that condition is true, then the loop would continue to call the API for data and print a message (taking data such as `percent_complete`) from the API and print a message to the user on the API response progress.

Finally, once `elif "meta in api_response:` (meaning the API response is now returning data), then I `return api_respone`, ready to be used by another function.

**Complete function** -

```
def api_call():

    key, secret, url = ini_reader()
    endpoint_url = endpoint_initializer()
    
    date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print("-------------------------------------\n","API URL constructed for:", date, "\n-------------------------------------")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------\n","Endpoint:", endpoint_url, "\n-------------------------------------------------------------")

    while True:
        response = requests.get(url = endpoint_url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(key, secret), headers = {"Vendor-firm": "443"})
        api_response = json.loads(response.text)
        if "meta" not in api_response:
            id_value = "id"
            res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
            id_value = "".join(res1)
            percent_value = "percent_complete"
            res2 = (tuple(api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '') for key, val in api_response.items()))
            print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {res2} complete!')
            time.sleep(5)
        elif "meta" in api_response:
            return api_response
api_call()
```